# Syncing my music on my new MBP, clarification needed

Tags: itunes

Got a new mac (yay!). Signed in to iTunes. Music library is .. empty.

How can I get my library to appear in my Itunes please?

Comment: Store menu > Check for available downloads ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Music Match it should all get transferred once you authorize the new computer. If you don't, then you will only be able to download the music you have purchased in iTunes. You need to make sure your computer is authorized - you can have up to five devices associated with the same account.